# update column value of data.table in R based on another column values

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)

train <- fread(input = "../train.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE, data.table = TRUE)

train$Response <- "" #create new column with values ""
train$Response <- paste(train[, 15:20, with = FALSE], collapse = "")

RStudio console:
> is.data.frame(train)
[1] TRUE
> is.data.table(train)
[1] TRUE
```

Columns with indexes from 15 to 20 has values = 1 or 0 of int type.

I have tryied to make one column "response" (character type) with values "0101..." as result of concatenation values 1 and 0 of columns, described above.

After this procedure I see abnormal behaviour of R studio, can't access to train etc.

Maybe something wrong?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense at the moment (since data.tables don't naturally use the "$"-operator). If `train` is a data.table then you should [edit] your question to construct an example that creates an object similar to your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the columns to `paste` in `.SDcols`, use `paste0` with `do.call` on the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), and assign (`:=`) to create the 'Response' column.

```
train[, Response := do.call(paste0, .SD), .SDcols = 15:20]
```